# Responsive CSS triangle that resizes according to its parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a CSS triangle that resizes itself according to the width of the parent.

Currently I have given custom size for the triangle I have created so that on resizing, the triangle starts to come outside of the parent. But I need the triangle to stay inside the parent on resizing but take full width. Please help. Thank you.

Here is my HTML and CSS.

```css
.triangle-container{
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.triangle{
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-left:167px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-right:167px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top:100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: by using jquery you can take the height and width of outer element and give it to the inner element, is this something you are looking for?

Comment: A relative border width is based on the div it surrounds, not the div that surrounds it, so this wouldn't be possible using your current approach

Comment: Is there any other method to achieve this without using jquery(using only css) @Anthony ?

Comment: @aug ... How do I add the "code snippet" feature ?

Comment: @Lost [Relevant blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). If you look in the GUI when posting an answer/question next to the Insert Image icon, there's a little code snippet icon for inserting code.

Comment: @aug Thank you so much. Trying to do things properly now :) SO can be rather intimidating at times.

Comment: @Lost of course :) I went ahead and updated your answer to show a code snippet instead.

Answer (score 4):

One posibility: use a multiple background to create the triangle. The element is set to take half the height of the parent, and the full width

```css
.triangle-container{
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.triangle{
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%, red 50%),
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%, red 50%);
  background-size: 50.2% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left, top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is the jagged edges on the triangle border. Is there a way to do this where the border lines are smooth?

Answer (score 0):

K this isn't a triangle but it looks like you trying to make an envelope shape... so here is how I would do it, change border etc. accordingly:

```css
.triangle-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.triangle {
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -500px;
  margin-top: -500px;
  border-left: 500px solid transparent;
  border-right: 500px solid transparent;
  border-top: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: For a triangle shape change following css properties of triangle-container to:

```
        width: 100%;            
        padding-left: 50%;
        padding-top: 50%;
```

and triangle:

```
        width:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using viewport relative units, something in this sense:

```
.triangle-container{
  width:50%;
  height:500px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle{
  width:50vw;
  height:50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50vw;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: purple;
}
```

Preview:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEdREr?editors=110